# How best to request data only once for each route in a Sapper app

Tags: store, svelte, preload, sapper

I'm fetching data from a GraphQL API for each page in a Sapper app. I could request all the API content for the different pages in the `_layout`'s `preload` function, I know that. The API is probably fast enough for it not too be an issue.

But... I'd prefer to just get the content for the current page. It just feels right. But I only want to get it once for each page. What's the best way to do that? If I run the preload on every route, it requests the content again if a user revisits the same page. Which is silly. Within the preload function, you can add the data to a store but you can't read the store in the preload function, so have no way to test whether it's been populated or not.

Comment: run preload on each route to get data that you need for each page?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the caching the request using the service-worker file, in the Discord channel. That worked. And there's also the Sapper export method, but that won't work because it'd need re-exporting every time the client updates the content in the API (not very often, but regularly enough).

Comment: _layout is just calling a function called preload. Preload is implemented individually in every route.